# Nested loops with mysql_query makes infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

Sorry for the title, but I couldn't be more specific (english is not my native language). Here's my problem: I've got 2 while loops with mysql_query() as expression (I know it's deprecated but I have to use it). And while the first loop is fine, the second one is infinitive loop and I don't know why. I tested mysql query in phpMyAdmin and it's fine. Here's my code:

```
while($czat = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablicacms_users` WHERE `id` = \"{$czat['user_id']}\""));


$feed = $feed.'

<div class="container dropshadow">
<div class="sidebar">
    <img class="avatar" src="../'.$user['avatar'].'" />
</div>
<div class="container2">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="username">'.$user['user'].'</div>
            <div class="datetime">'.$czat['timestamp'].'</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            '.$czat['message'].'
        </div>
        <div class="answer">odpowiedz<div style="display:none;">'.$czat['id'].'</div></div>
</div>
</div>

<br />';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20")))
{
    $reply_user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablicacms_users` WHERE `id` = \"{$row['user_id']}\""));
    $feed = $feed . '
        <div class="odpowiedzi">
            <div class="sidebar3"><img src="../'.$reply_user['avatar'].'" /></div>
            <div class="container3">
                <div class="info">'.$reply_user['user'].'</div>
                <div class="timestamp">'.$row['timestamp'].'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="reply">'.$row['message'].'</div>
        </div>
    ';
}

$feed = $feed . '
<div class="form_odpowiedz" id="'.$czat['id'].'">   
    <img src="../'.$user['avatar'].'" class="avatar2" />
    <form action="" name="odpowiedz"">
        <input type="textbox" name="text" class="text_odpowiedz" id="msg_reply_'.$czat['id'].'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="'.$czat['id'].'" class="msg_id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Odpowiedz" style="heigth: 30px;" class="odpowiedz" alt="'.$czat['id'].'" />
    </form>
    <br />
</div>


';}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: please try to `join` query

Comment: Deprecated mysql_query is your least problem. You are mixing HTML, PHP, SQL and CSS all together. Good luck with debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`czat2`WHERE`reply`= \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY`id`DESC LIMIT 20")))`

To,

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { /* your logic here */}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the query statement from the second while loop. In your statement

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20")))
```

what you are doing is querying the same statement everytime in the while loop. This has resulted in an infinite loop.
Make it something like this:-

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20")
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 //you stuff goes here
 }
```

This will work fine. Test it.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20"))
```

is executing over and over again. You are firing off the same query over and over and are fetching its first result over and over. You need to run the *query* once, then only fetch from the result in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you're re-executing the query every loop iteration.

Instead of :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20")))
{
```

Do

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `czat2` WHERE `reply` = \"{$czat['id']}\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```